# rails: devise auth system with 2 types of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am using devise for my auth system in rails.

I have 2 types of users, say students and teachers.

Student has access to profile. Teachers have access to gradebook.

How should this be implemented in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your talking about two different things, Devise is an Authentication tool, You want an Authorization tool like CanCan or some other custom Role/Permission System